# Mongoose not outputting what i want it to

Tags: javascript, mongoose

Have a look at my code:

```
    getGuildMemberExp(member) {
        return new Promise(async (fulfill, reject) => {
           try {
             let data = (await LevelsSchema.findOne({guild: member.guild.id, user: member.id})).exp || 0
             fulfill(data)
            } catch(err) {
                console.log(err)
                reject(err)
           }
        })
    }
```

As you can tell , i want it to output 0 if it doesn't find a result , but sadly i can't get it to work and it always outputs 0 when i know for a fact there is a result.

Comment: Can't you just remove the `exp` and the `|| 0` from assignment then call `fullfill(data.exp || 0)`?

Comment: nope , doesn't work

Comment: You should split up each step and `console.log` each variable after each step, do you get results from just the `await LevelsSchema.findOne()`?

Answer (score 0):

So, You are trying to compare async and sync results together and because sync gets resolved before async it will always return 0.

```
let data = (await LevelsSchema.findOne({guild: member.guild.id, user: member.id})).exp || 0
```

try changing above to,

```
let data = (await LevelsSchema.findOne({guild: member.guild.id, user: member.id})).exp

if(!data)
 data = 0
```